# Why can't I edit position of dropdownlist in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I cannot edit (it gets highlighted as brown) the dropdownlist control "Top" field in source view, in asp.net, when using Visual Studio:

I CAN edit the image control below it though!

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="AccountIdent" 
            DataValueField="AccountIdent"           
            style="top: 102px; left: 0px; position: absolute; height: 24px; width: 114px; z-index: 1;">
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server"             
        style="top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; height: 23px; width: 47px" />
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

I think it happens because the `asp:Image` will generate a single tag `<img/>` and the dropdown list will generate more tags.

You should use CssClasses, if you don't want to put it in another file you can use it in your page (it always a good idea to maintain css in other files), like:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .drop{
     top: 102px; left: 0px; position: absolute; height: 24px; width: 114px; z-index: 1;
  }
  .image{
     top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; height: 23px; width: 47px
  }
</style>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="AccountIdent" 
                DataValueField="AccountIdent" CssClass="drop">
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" CssClass="image"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`DropdownList` doesn't have `Style`  Attribute that's why you are unable to set it.For solution create a css class with those attribute and set `cssClass` of `dropdownList` to that class

like

```
<style>
    .anyname {
        top: 102px; left: 0px; position: absolute; height: 24px; width: 114px; z-index: 1;
    }
</style>
```

and in dropdown 
set

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="AccountIdent" 
            DataValueField="AccountIdent"  CssClass="anyname">         
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: But the code I posted was auto-generated by VS when I dragged and dropped the dropdownlist control in Design mode! Why would VS do that if it is incorrect?!

Comment: i don't know that maybe i am right person to answer this , because this question may have many answers , maybe its bug or maybe some kind of control related issue.. i found this link maybe this is helpful for you https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2008/03/11/absolute-and-relative-positioning-in-visual-web-developer-2008-designer/